# monero-wallet-cli and monerod has different block height

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli

Running `monero-wallet-cli` on macOS gives me this error:

```
The wallet's refresh-from-block-height setting is higher than the daemon's height: this may mean your wallet will skip over transactions
```

The wallet CLI then quits.

Poking around I have found out that the wallet block height is 2365949, and monerod lists height as 1273180/2365980.

I have tried to do a `rescan_bc` on the wallet from a lower height, but this has no effect.

So I think maybe I should change the height on `monerod`.

Looking at the monerod command line options I can't see a way to change it - or is there some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: May not be a problem.  Both are catching up.  monerod to blockchain and the wallet to monerod.

Comment: "monerod lists height as 1273180/2365980." <- your daemon is not fully synchronized.

Comment: @Dave and @jtgrassie - You are right, the problem went away once `monerod` got synchronized. There's no mention of this in the docs or any of the guides I have found, so it's easy to miss this point. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...monerod lists height as 1273180/2365980

Your daemon is not fully synchronized.

When fully sync'ed, you won't get the wallet message mentioned.